# What are my options for erosion control under this fence?

Tags: fence, retaining-wall

I am looking at options for mitigating erosion under this fence area. It is also an easement area shared with us and the higher neighboring property. I need: 1. A simple and cost effective solution to reduce erosion at the fence line along the entire fence
[image: Fence img #1]

[image: Fence img #2]

[image: Fence img #4]

[image: Fence img #5]

The other side of the fence:
[image: Neighbor side of fence]

The other side of the fence:
[image: Neighbor side of fence #2]

[image: Fence #3]

Comment: A picture of the other side of wooden fence might help.

Comment: Does the slope continue on the other side of the fence?  And who does the fence belong to?

Comment: And which wall are you asking about?  The one along the bottom of the hill, or the one that's partially built next to the fence?  If it's the latter, then it's really not a retaining wall, at least IMHO.

Comment: Really trying to work out what options we have here to work with.....aesthetically and practically. The areas on both sides of the fence are a utilities easement, and I am not clear who the fence belongs to.  That is likely an important factor to ascertain!

Comment: You may consider talking to the utility company and/or a property lawyer to find out what rights you may have to make any modifications within the easement. Your best bet for erosion control probably planting low ground cover, and providing somewhere controlled for the water to go should it flood.

Answer (score 1):

Stating the obvious. Grass. Other than that you have all dirt. Wind and water will continue the erosion. Grass seed is cheap. Try hay, if it is not windy in your area,bales of hay cost $12. You will need 3. Break them down and throw seed in, let weeds and grass grow.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the fence posts are erected properly with adequate embedment length, the only thing you need to address is to avoid soil erosion or loss of surface soil due to weathering. I'll provide a 1' - 2' wide x 6" deep stone bench next to the fence, then buildup and smoother the slope with topsoil and populate it with vegetation, but no trees.